# AFNetworking Pods installation not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, afnetworking, cocoapods

I cloned a repo I'm working on from GitHub and I ran `pod install` on it. The Xcode project has many dependencies (all of which are installed using Cocoapods), however, the only error I am getting is with `AFNetworking`.

Here's the error I am getting :

[image]

Every other dependency is working and its setup exactly the way AFNetworking is, however, all the AFNetworking classes are not being recognized. Any help ?

Here's the `podfile`:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

target 'Name' do
    pod 'AFNetworking'
    pod 'MWPhotoBrowser'
    pod 'STPopup'
    pod 'KINWebBrowser'
    pod 'JMImageCache'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
end

target 'NameTests' do

end

target 'NameUITests' do

end
```

Comment: What is your set up?  Are you writing Swift or Objective-C?  Which version of AFNetworking, and why not Alamofire?  Also, do you have Bitcode enabled?  Please paste your podfile if possible

Comment: Latest version of AFNetworking is being used, app uses both Objective-C and Swift, edited post to include `podfile`, Bitcode is enabled.

Comment: Off the top of my head, you'll have to add `AFNetworking.h` to your Objective-C bridging header, since AFN is an Objective-C framework.  I expect you are not having problems in your Objective-C classes?

Comment: The bridging header has `<AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>` in it.

Comment: Hmm...here's a recommendation that has worked for me before...http://stackoverflow.com/a/24102433/239318

Comment: Since you're using Swift, go with Alamofire instead of AFNetworking

Answer (score 0):

Update your AFNetworking.Make sure CocoaPods 0.39.0+ is required to build AFNetworking 3.0.0+.

Answer (score 0):

try this

1.first remove all form podfile then  hit pod install

2. after that put back all the file  and hir pod install

it will remove akn install your pods again

hope it will work.works for me as well

Answer (score 0):

**AFHTTPRequestOperation** and **AFHTTPRequestOperationManager** are not available in 3.0.0. It has been removed. Please see this [guide](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-3.0-Migration-Guide)