# Developing for Microsoft Band on iOS

Tags: xcode, swift, microsoft-band

After creating a swift-based iPhone app, I have added the band .framework file into my xcode project. I then created a header file including:

```
#ifndef BandHeader_h
#define BandHeader_h

#import <MicrosoftBandKit_iOS/MicrosoftBandKit_iOS.h>

#endif /* BandHeader_h */
```

when I try to initialise MSBClient ViewController.swift, it says use of undeclared type, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Bridging Header import issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24146677/swift-bridging-header-import-issue)

Comment: you will need a bridging header setup, not only directly importing like this.

Comment: I followed the linked post, it still complains about not finding the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps in this answer will help: [Swift "Bridging-Header.h" file not allowing me to instantiate objective-c classes in .swift files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102386/swift-bridging-header-h-file-not-allowing-me-to-instantiate-objective-c-classe)

In general, you need a bridging header and you must set that in your build steps so it can be found.

You can also see an example of a bridging header in use for the Microsoft Band Kit here: https://github.com/mthistle/MicrosoftBandKit_iOS-Swift2/tree/master/BandSensor/BSwiftHeartRate