# Bridging-Header Does not exists

Tags: swift, xcode, bridging-header

I have added the bridging header in my project , but then also I getting error of "ProjectName \ ProjectName - Bridging-Header.h" file does not exists.

Comment: Have you done it as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24102433/5576310)?

Comment: Yes , i have done same.

Comment: Check this too https://stackoverflow.com/a/31716660/2594560

Comment: Yes , i am doing this since day before yesterday. i don't know how much time i have recreated the Bridging header file , i have also recreated the project for checking but then to facing same problem, please help me out.

Comment: can you share a snapshot of your file heirarchy/navigator pane (left) from Xcode?

Comment: https://imageshack.com/i/pmiO5qN7p    @Malik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your build settings, give a complete address to your bridging header instead of `testLogin/testLogin-Bridging-Header.h`